# onClickListener is called only after soft-keyboard press

Tags: java, android, keyboard, onclicklistener

I write an android app

I set an `editText.setOnClickListener(...)`

but i see that when the user clicks, the soft-keyboard is opened and only

when the user clicks on a keyboard key - the `onClick()` is called.

how to catch the click before the soft keyboard is opened?

I want to avoid the keyboard opening.

here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.phone_login);
    initMembers();
    setOnClickListeners();
    initFieldsTexts();
    setKeyboardVisibilityListener();
}

private void setOnClickListeners() {

    mPhoneNumberField.setInputTextOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
            finish();
        }
    });

}
```

and:

```
public class PhoneLoginFillInField extends LinearLayout {
..
    public void setInputTextOnClickListener(OnClickListener onClickListener)
    {
        mInputText.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    }
```

during debugging i see this line is called twice

`mPhoneNumberField.setInputTextOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {`

though it's called only from onCreate and there `setOnClickListeners();` is called once

Comment: So you don't want the keyboard to open up when you click on edittext?

Comment: i want to move the user to another view instead

Comment: Can you please post your code for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set an onTouchListener to the EditView. Remember to return true to avoid the event propagation.

Comment: why we don't have boolean return in `public void onClick(View v)`? can you better explain this propagation issue?

Comment: The View.onTouch method returns "True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise". In the second case, the event will be propagated to the view hierarchy so the parent views can handle the event themselves. In your case you will consume the event in your editText, so you must return true in the onTouch method.

Comment: why we don't have boolean return in public void onClick(View v)?

Answer (score 1):

You mean EditText should not gain focus; it needs to respond only to click events. Do this:

```
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

And then carry on:

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
       // Your code...
   }
}
```

Comment: btw, when debugging I see code that sets the onClickListener is executed twice. Though it's in called once only from the "onCreate". How come?

Comment: It shouldn't be set twice. If you are debugging in Eclipse and you have a breakpoint exactly where you set the onClickListener and when you press Step Over (F6) you see it keeps you on the same line this is nothing to worry about. It just initializes the new OnClickListener and then sets it to your EditText. I think the behavior is the same in Android Studio and InteliJ.
On the other hand, if it really does execute the code inside the overriden onClick() method twice then there really is a problem. You should post code for more help.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted. I don't undersdtand exactly what the problem is. You didn't specify if the overriden onClick method is called unexpectedly. I mean, if this block of code is executed in onCreate: setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
finish();